# Issue Adding Android Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

so I am currently working on a basic event organiser, it will store events for a convention and allow the user to store the events they're interested in.

However I am having issues, as i want to add a dialog to each buttons press so it will display the events information and give the user the option if they want to add it or not.

The issue i am having with the code is the following, which occours onclick.

***android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application***

Below is the code for the eventbutton itself which is displayed on screen

```
   public class EventButton extends Button
{
    public Button button = this;
    public Event event;
    public String eventHost;
    public String eventName;
    public String eventLocation;
    public Calendar eventDate;
    private LinearLayout screen;

    public EventButton(Context context , Event pEvent){
        super(context);
        eventDate = pEvent.eventDate;
        eventName = pEvent.eventName;
        eventHost = pEvent.eventHost;
        eventLocation = pEvent.eventLocation;
        event = pEvent;
        setOnClick();

        this.setText(eventName + "\n " + eventHost);
    }

     public void setOnClick() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                int timeTilEvent =getTimeDifference();
                int day = eventDate.get(eventDate.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month=eventDate.get(eventDate.MONTH);
                int year=eventDate.get(eventDate.YEAR);
                int hour=eventDate.get(eventDate.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute=eventDate.get(eventDate.MINUTE);
                String minutestring=""+ minute;

                if(minutestring.length()==1){
                    minutestring = "0"+minute;
                }
                String dateOutput= day + "/" + month +"/" + year + "\n " + hour + ":" + minutestring;

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Event:" + eventName + "\n Host:" + eventHost + "\n Location: " + eventLocation + "\n When: " + dateOutput);
                builder.setTitle("do you wish to add this event to your watch list?");

                if(!FileManager.eventList.contains(event)) {
                    builder.setPositiveButton("add interest", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            FileManager.writeToFile(new Event(eventHost, eventName, eventLocation, eventDate), getContext());
                            FileManager.readFromFile(getContext());
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if(FileManager.eventList.contains(event)) {
                    builder.setPositiveButton("remove interest", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            FileManager.eventList.remove(event);
                            FileManager.writeToFile(new Event(eventHost, eventName, eventLocation, eventDate), getContext());
                            FileManager.readFromFile(getContext());
                        }
                    });
                }

                builder.setPositiveButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

Main class (showing how the buttons are created)

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Calendar setupDate(int year, int month, int day , int hour, int minute){
        return new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day,hour,minute);
    }    

    ArrayList<EventButton> buttons = new ArrayList<EventButton>();

    public void addButtonToList(String pHost, String pName,String pEventLocation, Calendar pDate){
        Event event = new Event(pHost, pName, pEventLocation, pDate);
        buttons.add(new EventButton(getBaseContext(),event));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        addButtonToList("Host ", " Event", "location", setupDate(2016, 04, 03, 10, 00));
       addButtonToList("Host ", " Event", "location", setupDate(2016, 04, 03, 10, 00));



        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for(int count=0;count < buttons.size();count++){
            if(buttons.get(count) != null) {
                buttons.get(count).AddButtonToScreen(ll, lp);
            }
        }



        }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks

(the catlog output if anyone was interested or needed it)

```
    04-03 18:26:20.267 4335-4335/? E/Zygote: v2
04-03 18:26:20.267 4335-4335/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10160
04-03 18:26:20.267 4335-4335/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
04-03 18:26:20.267 4335-4335/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G361F_5.1.1_0043
04-03 18:26:20.267 4335-4335/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
04-03 18:26:20.277 4335-4335/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-03 18:26:20.287 4335-4335/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
04-03 18:26:20.307 4335-4335/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
04-03 18:26:20.307 4335-4335/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
04-03 18:26:20.307 4335-4335/? I/SAMP: ActivityThread() - SAMP_ENABLE : true
04-03 18:26:20.357 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
04-03 18:26:20.367 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
04-03 18:26:20.367 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
04-03 18:26:20.437 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
04-03 18:26:20.447 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
04-03 18:26:20.447 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
04-03 18:26:20.447 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
04-03 18:26:20.457 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
04-03 18:26:20.497 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
04-03 18:26:20.497 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
04-03 18:26:20.557 4335-4398/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-03 18:26:20.577 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
04-03 18:26:20.577 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
04-03 18:26:20.627 4335-4398/com.example.daniel.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-03 18:26:20.627 4335-4398/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/GC: <tid=4398> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC version rls_5011p6_GC5.5.14 
04-03 18:26:20.637 4335-4398/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-03 18:26:20.757 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-03 18:26:20.757 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@25ba99d time:70384960
04-03 18:26:32.137 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@25ba99d time:70396347
04-03 18:26:33.527 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-03 18:26:33.647 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : true
04-03 18:26:33.647 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : 8388610
04-03 18:26:33.687 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-03 18:26:33.687 4335-4335/com.example.daniel.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.daniel.myapplication, PID: 4335
                                                                                android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:578)
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                                    at com.example.daniel.myapplication.EventButton$1.onClick(EventButton.java:195)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: What issues are you having with your app?

Comment: i keep getting this error

   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Could you share your catlog?

Comment: i couldn't add it to a comment but i added it to the bottom of the main post

Comment: @daniel that is the correct thing to do anyway, always add clarifying info as an edit to the question, as comments can be deleted at any time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Base Context when you should be using the Activity Context.

Instead of using `getBaseContext()`, just use `this` for the Activity Context:

```
public void addButtonToList(String pHost, String pName,String pEventLocation, Calendar pDate){
    Event event = new Event(pHost, pName, pEventLocation, pDate);
    buttons.add(new EventButton(this, event));
}
```